# "Disputed low quality review" automatic flag reports more delete votes than "looks good" when it is not so

Tags: bug, flags, low-quality-posts, automatic-flags

Looking at the flags in the moderator queue, I noticed the following automatic flag.

> [image: screenshot]

Clicking on the "review task" link I see the following.

> [image: screenshot]

The votes are actually one for deletion and one for "looks good." Such situation should not be reported as "more delete votes than 'looks good'"; either the text should be fixed to not indicate "more" reviews, or a flag should not be raised in this case.

Comment: Psychic debugging: they meant "both kinds of vote".

Comment: I just saw this today, only difference being an actual delete vote versus "recommend deletion".  As Tim Stone said [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238967/162102), math has been hard for a while.  Re "possibly it should avoid...": as a moderator I want to know if an NAA or VLQ flag was left in limbo.  If it's in the review queue, great.  If reviewers resolved it one way or the other, great.  But if reviewers were conflicted, I want a flag for that.