# Community♦ can't count: 1 is not greater than 1

Tags: bug, review, flags

Community♦ raises auto-flags for disputed reviews, like this:

[image: review snippet]

Note the report of "more delete votes than 'looks good'".  I was curious about the details, so I looked at the review and found this:

[image: review report]

One "Looks ok", one "Delete".  How is that "*more* delete votes than 'looks good'"?

(Also, side issue, but shouldn't that be 'looks ok' now?)

Comment: And the question itself didn't have preexisting delete votes?

Comment: I see one delete vote there now, presumably the one from the review.  (If the link would be helpful, I'm happy to supply it in an appropriate venue.)

Comment: Math has been hard for a while, apparently. Or the message is just confusing and is actually meant to say "There were votes that conflict with 'looks OK'"