# While reviewing questions in the Low quality posts queue, the reviewed item should display the content of the post

Tags: feature-request, review, questions, low-quality-posts

Following [How can a low quality post can get more than 15 or 20 reviewers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356261/209901), I found out that currently you cannot view the content of the question you just reviewed in the Low quality post review queue.

Instead, you just the set of actions other reviewers (and you) have done. See for example on https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/230955:

> [image]

See the difference with a review to an answer, for example on https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/240689, where the content of the post appears normally:

> [image]

Comment: @Rob no, it is not deleted. I just found it --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/387770/83 now finally closed thanks to a mod vote. My vote to close from the LQP review queue seems to have been counted in. The timeline is funny to see: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/387770/timeline