# I have three pending suggested edits but there appears to be only one post in the Suggested edits queue

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits

I have three pending Suggested edits on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), however there appears to be only one post in the Suggested edits queue:

[image: comparison of my suggested edits with length of suggested edits queue]

Here are the three links to the pending suggested edits: [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/21074), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/21073), and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/21072) (which I give not in the expectation that they will be handled but in case anybody needs to review their activity).

[Review overview shows two suggested edits for a long time, but the review queue is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246805/review-overview-shows-two-suggested-edits-for-a-long-time-but-the-review-queue) discusses a different situation (which may be connected) whereby a reviewer could see there was a queue, but there was nothing in the queue.

I can imagine that the status of the review queues are not updated immediately, however I would have expected that the status of the review queues are updated at least once an hour, if not more often. Perhaps this is connected with caching, however these suggested edits were made more than 24 hours ago.

I have a low reputation on ELL (currently 109) without access to any review queues. However, I can see the [statistics of the review queues on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review), which are at the moment:

| Number of Posts | Review Queue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 post | First questions |
| 0 posts | First answers |
| 0 posts | Late answers |
| 2 posts | Low quality posts |
| 1 post | Suggested edits |
| 91 posts | Close votes |
| 0 posts | Reopen votes |

[Somebody needs to watch the health of review queues, network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395686/1242908), which has recently been posted, is probably connected and relevant.

I noticed this earlier on two other [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) sites, so this probably applies to all sites (however I no longer have any pending suggested edits on those other sites).

**After posting this question**, I was informed by a >25K user that they could see "4 need review" in the suggested edit queue. So, checking again, I confirmed that I could still see "1 need review" and the thought crossed my mind that the suggested edit queue statistics are showing me the "length of the queue" minus "my pending edits".

Is this the case, and if so why?

Comment: Says 4 need review when I look at the stats page.

Comment: @RobertLongson I still see only 1 need review on the stats page (from both my mobile phone network as well as cable ... if that is relevant)

Comment: @RobertLongson Could it be that the suggested edit queue statistics are showing me the "length of the queue" minus "my pending edits" ?

Comment: I only see 1 as needing review, both as an ELL moderator and in incognito window. But I think I was seeing 4 as a moderator when I first saw your meta post. I wonder how many actually need review. (Didn't skip any.)

Comment: @Laurel I still have 3 pending edits and I can now see "1 need review" and in incognito mode, I can now see "4 need review" ... and "0 reviews today", just in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot review your own suggested edits, so the system is indeed subtracting your three edits from the four in total. When you open the page when you're not logged in (e.g. in a private browser window, or another browser), you'll see 4 posts/reviews, just like everybody else.

The same would hold for e.g. Close Votes when one of your own questions is in the queue - then you'd see one post less than everybody else.

Comment: Yes, I can now see 0 need review when I am logged in and 3 need review in an "incognito" window.